# Subdivision Surface modifier works badly

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I try to follow instruction from an old video tutorial of creating a clock. This is what I wanna achieve (I mean smooth edges only):

[image: How it should be]

And this is my work without SubSurf:

[image: Clock without subsur]

This is what I get with Subdivision Surface modifier:

[image: Clock with subsur]

How can I rid of ugly rim / hollow on the left side of screenshot? It looks terrible after rendering! I tried to use different subdivisions numbers and replace it with bevel, but nothing helps.

This is my work from other side without the modifier:

[image]

And why did I get this problem if I tried to follow all the steps and proportions of the tutorial?

**Update**

I highlighted the problem here:

[image]

Comment: After reading the question I am still unsure what you actually want. Maybe [removing doubles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#remove-doubles) will work for you?

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny I've added a representative screenshot. And yes, I solved the problem, it was because of plenty double vertices  So many problems because of them...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do Ctrl + R to add a loop cut, click before the sharp vertices you want, and just slide it to the left to sharp the angle
Otherwise you can select the vertices and in the Tool box on the right (with N) click on a thing with crease in the name, or I think you can do Shift + E

Comment: Thanks, I tried your advices, but it turned out that the problem was because of silly double vertices...